# Salesforce CPQ Quote Line Editor, Field to enter Additiona Discount % or USD

Tags: cpq

In [image: Salesforce CPQ Quote Line Editor] header by default we have Additional Discount(%), i wish to add additional functionality for this, so i can enter Discount % or USD. See screenshot, kindly suggest how i can achieve it? see attached image.

Answer (score 0):

There are some special fields in Salesforce CPQ that don't exist initially, but admin can create them manually and modify. One of this field is `AdditionalDiscountUnit`.
You need to manually create it following considerations in this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314788&type=1&mode=1&language=en_US).

Then you can specify what values (units) are available for users to see/select. Users will see picklist in QLE instead of just number field.